# Can ptrace cause the traced process to perform a syscall without access to an executable syscall instruction?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, ptrace

Consider this simple program that just infinitely loops:

```
int main(void) {
        for(;;);
}
```

It's easy enough to use `ptrace` to inject a system call into it, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        struct user_regs_struct regs;
        pid_t pid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
        waitid(P_PID, pid, NULL, WSTOPPED);
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, (void*)regs.rip, (void*)0x050f /* the "syscall" instruction, in little-endian */)) {
                perror("PTRACE_POKETEXT");
                return 1;
        }
        regs.rax = SYS_exit;
        regs.rdi = 42;
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

That will inject the syscall `_exit(42);` over the infinite loop. It's also possible to do this by looking for an existing `syscall` instruction instead of just overwriting wherever the instruction pointer happens to be.

Now consider this program, that also (after some setup) just infinitely loops:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

struct mapping_list {
    void *start;
    size_t len;
    struct mapping_list *next;
};

typedef void unmap_all_t(struct mapping_list *list, void *start, size_t len);
extern unmap_all_t unmap_all;
extern const char unmap_all_end[];
__asm__("\n"
    "unmap_all:\n"
    "  movq %rsi, %r8 # save start\n"
    "  movq %rdi, %r9 # save list\n"
    ".unmap_list_element:\n"
    "  movq (%r9), %rdi # pass list->start as addr\n"
    "  movq 8(%r9), %rsi # pass list->len as length\n"
    "  movl $11, %eax # SYS_munmap\n"
    "  syscall\n"
    "  movq 16(%r9), %r9 # advance to the next list element\n"
    "  testq %r9, %r9\n"
    "  jne .unmap_list_element\n"
    "  movl $11, %eax # SYS_munmap\n"
    "  movq %r8, %rdi # pass start as addr\n"
    "  movq %rdx, %rsi # pass len as length\n"
    "  jmp .final_syscall\n"
    "  .org unmap_all+4094 # make sure the upcoming syscall instruction is at the very end of the page,\n"
    ".final_syscall:       # given that unmap_all started at the very beginning of it\n"
    "  syscall\n"
    ".loop_forever:\n"
    "  jmp .loop_forever\n"
    "unmap_all_end:\n"
);

int main(void) {
    FILE *maps = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if(!maps) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    struct mapping_list *list = NULL;
    unsigned long start, end;
    char r, w, x;
    while(fscanf(maps, "%lx-%lx %c%c%c", &start, &end, &r, &w, &x) == 5) {
        while(fgetc(maps) != '\n');
        if(x != 'x') continue;
        struct mapping_list *new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct mapping_list));
        new_list->start = (void*)start;
        new_list->len = end - start;
        new_list->next = list;
        list = new_list;
    }

    if(fclose(maps)) {
        perror("fclose");
        return 1;
    }

    int memfd = syscall(SYS_memfd_create, "unmap_all", 2 /* MFD_ALLOW_SEALING */);
    if(memfd == -1) {
        perror("memfd_create");
        return 1;
    }

    if(ftruncate(memfd, 8192)) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        return 1;
    }

    char *pages = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memfd, 0);
    if(pages == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy(pages, unmap_all, unmap_all_end - (const char*)unmap_all);

    if(munmap(pages, 8192)) {
        perror("munmap");
        return 1;
    }

    char *path;
    if(asprintf(&path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", memfd) == -1) {
        perror("asprintf");
        return 1;
    }

    int memfd_ro = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if(memfd_ro == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    free(path);

    if(fcntl(memfd, 1033 /* F_ADD_SEALS */, 15 /* F_SEAL_SEAL|F_SEAL_SHRINK|F_SEAL_GROW|F_SEAL_WRITE */)) {
        perror("fcntl");
        return 1;
    }

    if(close(memfd)) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    }

    pages = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, memfd_ro, 0);
    if(pages == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }

    if(close(memfd_ro)) {
        perror("close");
        return 1;
    }

    ((unmap_all_t*)pages)(list, pages, 4096);

    __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

When I try to use my ptrace program on it, the `PTRACE_POKETEXT` step to write the syscall instruction fails with error `EIO`, since the containing page is a shared mapping of a read-only file. I also don't have the option to find an existing `syscall` instruction, as all executable pages except one have been unmapped, and the sole remaining one doesn't contain that instruction anywhere.

Is there any other way to use `ptrace` to cause that program to execute a syscall, or have I made that completely impossible? (If it matters, assume Linux 4.19 on x86_64.)

Comment: Save some bytes from the tracee memory, write your instructions there, execute the system call, restore saved bytes.

Comment: Following n.m.'s guideline, after attaching to the process, using `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT`, `PTRACE_POKETEXT`, `PTRACE_GETREGS`, `PTRACE_SETREGS` can be used to set up for the syscall. After that, `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` on the actual injected `syscall` instruction. Then, restore all. Here's a helper library: https://github.com/emptymonkey/ptrace_do that has some code. Note that you do _not_ need to find an existing `syscall`, just enough space in the text segment to inject one (e.g. two bytes is enough)

Comment: @CraigEstey The program in my question unmaps the entirety of its own text segment.

Comment: @n.m. The only executable page is non-writable. Does ptrace provide some way to write to a `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC`, `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` page?

Comment: If that were true, the `jmp .loop_forever` would be unmapped, so are you sure?

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes. That program creates a new executable page, copies that bit of asm in, then arranges for it to be the next instruction after it munmaps itself.

Comment: If you have _any_ mapped text _page_, you have (e.g.) 4096 bytes to poke with `ptrace`, so I don't think it's a problem. AFAIK, `PTRACE_POKETEXT` will write to R/O pages that the target process can't [check the return code to verify this]. You could check `/proc/pid/maps` and do `readlink` on `/proc/pid/map_files` entries to see where the new page got mapped. You can stop the process, then get the `RIP` value to know which page is the one you've created.

Comment: @CraigEstey I slightly modified the example program. Now, were `PTRACE_POKETEXT` to be able to write to the executable page, it would violate the guarantee provided by `F_SEAL_WRITE`.

Comment: I just posted on your other question about `F_SEAL_*` But, _what_ are you trying to do by doing `memfd` stuff for if it's related to this? That is, if you can `ptrace` a process, you _are_ trusted, so sealing isn't really required [my takeaway from manpage for `memfd_create`]

Comment: @CraigEstey The tracee implicitly trusts the tracer, but it's possible (although this program doesn't do it) to share the memfd with another program, one that wouldn't trust the tracer (or the tracee for that matter, hence the reason for seals' existence). The point of the seal is to "prove" that ptrace shouldn't automatically allow writing read-only pages.

Comment: @n.m. I built a program that does as you described, and it works against "normal" programs, but it fails against the program in my question. I edited details of my attempt into my question.

Answer (score 1):

> The point of the seal is to "prove" that ptrace shouldn't automatically allow writing read-only pages

Seals are related to normal shared memory access between processes.

As I mentioned on your other question, regarding kernel source:

`ptrace` access via `PTRACE_POKETEXT` is different. It completely bypasses the protections on a given page. (i.e.) It does *not* reference anything related to seals.

The poketext operation is handled by completely different code within the kernel and [sort of] just does it via access calls to the VM.

I wouldn't worry about it too much.

You might have a look at `CONFIG_HAVE_IOREMAP_PROT`

Comment: Using seals makes the `PTRACE_POKETEXT` trick to write a `syscall` instruction fail with `EIO`. I edited details of my attempt into the question, and I successfully tested it against a program that doesn't use seals to prove that it's the seals that break it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can ptrace cause the traced process to perform a syscall without access to an executable syscall instruction?

Only if the tracer can generate one using `POKETEXT`, using current mainline kernels and kernel modules.

---

Perhaps it is time to reread the first paragraph in [`man 2 ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> The ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process (the
>     "tracer") may observe and control the execution of another process
>     (the "tracee"), and examine and change the tracee's memory and
>     registers.  It is primarily used to implement breakpoint debugging
>     and system call tracing.

It is a tool for observing an controlling a tracee, not some kind of jail, nor an attacker that a process should protect themselves from.

There are probably other ways a tracee can set up a non-writable executable mapping, unmap all other pages, and ensure nothing in the executable pages left contain a sequence that can be used to construct a system call.

So what? Such cases have not yet popped up in practice, or we'd have modified [ptrace facilities](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/ptrace.c) to cover that case as well.

If this is a real problem, it seems to me that the best approach would be to add an explicit syscall facility to ptrace.  There are a number of options how it could be implemented.

So, any *"No"* answer to the stated question must be amended with *"we can add that feature if needed, though"*.  We don't even need to modify any existing kernels, I think; just write a helper kernel module providing the needed facilities.